# Is this the only way to extract form's input data from the new <dialog> element?

Tags: html, modal-dialog

I am using the new HTML dialog element in my react web app. In my render I have a dialog like this:

```
<dialog id={'dashboard-params' + this.hash} className={'dashboard-edit-form'}>
      <span className={'dialog-symbol'}> {this.symbol} - Make Your Changes Below.</span>
      <form method="dialog">
        <label htmlFor="watched">Watched</label>
        <input type="text" name="watched" value={this.watched} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="watchedPrice">WatchedPrice</label>
        <input type="text" name="watchedPrice" value={this.watchedPrice} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="session">Session</label>
        <input type="text" name="session" value={this.session} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <br />
        <button type="submit" value="no">
          Cancel
        </button>
        <button type="submit" value="yes">
          Save
        </button>
      </form>
    </dialog>
```

And in some later part of the HTML I have this button with a pencil image:

```
<button onClick={this.handleEditDashboardParams} className={'button-pencil-image-absolute'}>
```

And some JS like this:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.dialogDashboardParams = document.getElementById('dashboard-params' + this.hash)
      dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(this.dialogDashboardParams) // Now dialog acts like a native <dialog>.
  }



handleEditDashboardParams(event) {
  this.dialogDashboardParams.showModal()
  let self = this
  this.dialogDashboardParams.addEventListener('close', function(event) {
  if (self.dialogDashboardParams.returnValue === 'yes') {
    let data = []
    for (let k = 0; k < event.target.childNodes[3].length; k++) {
      data.push(event.target.childNodes[3][k].outerHTML)
      // now go thru the data array and use some regex to extract name/value pairs
    }
  }
})
```

}

Everything works fine, except for extracting the input data.

The only way I could find the input data was through a "for loop" on event.target.childNodes[3] as shown above. That gives me an array of strings like this:

```
<input type="text" name="watched" value="9/27/2018">
<input type="text" name="watchedPrice" value="51.28">
<input type="text" name="session" value="NORMAL">
```

I can use some regex to extract the name and value pairs. But is this the only way? 
There must be a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already keeping track of the value of each input in your state you can just access it that way.  So `this.session` for example.(Or I notice in your case, `self.session` to reach the outer context.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Later I found this helpful reference: reactjs.org/docs/forms.html. Thanks for answering.